How to resolve unkown session "startup" after Vacuum full
Last night we did a vacuum full operation on partitioned tables.
A few hours after the vacuum full, I found cpu rising with an unknown session called “startup” when queried by top command.
We cannot conclude that this is related to vacuum full.
But, I checked that startup was taken after autuvacuum ran in the pg_catalog table. such as pg_class,pg_attribute.
this is not even left in postgresql.log, and I couldn't get accurate information about this by searching.
We are using the postgresql15.3 version
And This is our top_total log by System activity report



   top - 10:35:09 up 33 days, 23:48, 12 users,  load average: 240.31, 111.23, 48.79

        PID    PPID USER        VIRT    RES    SHR  %CPU  %MEM COMMAND
    2979079 2931746 postgres   17.7g   1.1g   1.1g  18.6   3.8 postgres: startup
    2977705 2931746 postgres   17.7g   1.1g   1.1g  11.8   3.8 postgres: startup
    2978636 2931746 postgres   17.7g   1.1g   1.1g   6.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2979407 2931746 postgres   17.7g   1.1g   1.1g   6.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2984501 2931746 postgres   17.8g 711652 668320   6.9   2.2 postgres: SELECT
         74       2 root           0      0      0   5.9   0.0 [kcompactd0]
       2584       1 root      170536  35472   2464   5.9   0.1 /usr/local/aegis/aegis_client/aegis_11_83/AliYunDunMonitor
    2976958 2931746 postgres   17.6g   1.1g   1.1g   4.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2977028 2931746 postgres   17.6g   1.1g   1.1g   4.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2978115 2931746 postgres   17.7g   1.1g   1.1g   4.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2979350 2931746 postgres   17.7g   1.1g   1.1g   4.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2980154 2931746 postgres   17.7g   1.1g   1.1g   4.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2980160 2931746 postgres   17.7g   1.1g   1.1g   4.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2980192 2931746 postgres   17.7g   1.1g   1.1g   4.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2981112 2931746 postgres   17.7g 662892 659756   4.9   2.1 postgres: startup
    2981319 2931746 postgres   17.7g 663528 660392   4.9   2.1 postgres: startup
    2984821 2931746 postgres   17.8g 318768 307876   4.9   1.0 postgres: SELECT
    2986477 2931746 postgres   17.8g 118200 112736   4.9   0.4 postgres: SELECT
    2848228       1 root       32468  15656   6704   3.9   0.0 /usr/bin/python3 /sbin/iotop -botkP -n 3600
    2977197 2931746 postgres   17.6g   1.1g   1.1g   3.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2978532 2931746 postgres   17.7g   1.1g   1.1g   3.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2978662 2931746 postgres   17.7g   1.1g   1.1g   3.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2981088 2931746 postgres   17.7g 663464 660328   3.9   2.1 postgres: startup
    2982154 2931746 postgres   17.7g 663468 660328   3.9   2.1 postgres: startup
    2982402 2931746 postgres   17.7g 662888 659748   3.9   2.1 postgres: startup
    2983158 2931746 postgres   17.7g 663468 660328   3.9   2.1 postgres: startup
    2983260 2931746 postgres   17.7g 663468 660328   3.9   2.1 postgres: startup
    2984317 2931746 postgres   17.8g 447248 415620   3.9   1.4 postgres: SELECT
    2984643 2931746 postgres   17.8g 445384 418132   3.9   1.4 postgres: BIND
    2986410 2931746 postgres   17.8g 127636 122008   3.9   0.4 postgres: SELECT
    2848231       1 root       12540   9264   1800   2.9   0.0 pidstat -u -l 1 3600
    2976372 2931746 postgres   17.6g   1.1g   1.1g   2.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2976379 2931746 postgres   17.6g   1.1g   1.1g   2.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2976401 2931746 postgres   17.6g   1.1g   1.1g   2.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2976469 2931746 postgres   17.6g   1.1g   1.1g   2.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2976881 2931746 postgres   17.6g   1.1g   1.1g   2.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2976884 2931746 postgres   17.6g   1.1g   1.1g   2.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2976886 2931746 postgres   17.6g   1.1g   1.1g   2.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2976894 2931746 postgres   17.6g   1.1g   1.1g   2.9   3.8 postgres: startup
    2976896 2931746 postgres   17.8g   1.2g   1.2g   2.9   4.1 postgres: idle




We would like to know what "start up" means and why it happened and how we should act on this situation.
I look forward to your prompt reply.
Thank you.
mean of startup session
how to resolve  cpu rising with startup session
relation of startup and vacuum full
relation of startup and autovacuum
++add
I had a vacuum full on the pg_class table last night. Even now, start-up sessions are found intermittently.
We found that it took a long time in "connection authorized" when we re-proceded the vacuum for the table that did the vacuum full.
This is a detailed log


2024-06-24 14:40:30.875 KST [3620][][]DEBUG:  forked new backend, pid=243980 socket=9
2024-06-24 14:40:30.876 KST [3620][][]DEBUG:  forked new backend, pid=243981 socket=9
2024-06-24 14:40:30.876 KST [243980][[unknown]][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]LOG:  connection received: host=mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com port=16842
2024-06-24 14:40:30.877 KST [243980][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  InitPostgres
2024-06-24 14:40:30.877 KST [243980][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  my backend ID is 9
2024-06-24 14:40:30.877 KST [243981][[unknown]][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]LOG:  connection received: host=mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com port=16854
2024-06-24 14:40:30.877 KST [243980][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:30.877 KST [243981][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  InitPostgres
2024-06-24 14:40:30.877 KST [243981][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  my backend ID is 10
2024-06-24 14:40:30.877 KST [243980][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]LOG:  connection authorized: user= database=postgres application_name=psql
2024-06-24 14:40:30.877 KST [243981][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:30.878 KST [243981][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]LOG:  connection authorized: user= database=postgres application_name=psql

2024-06-24 14:40:31.016 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:31.016 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]LOG:  duration: 172.742 ms
2024-06-24 14:40:31.017 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:31.017 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]LOG:  statement: VACUUM pg_catalog.pg_class;
2024-06-24 14:40:31.017 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]LOG:  parse tree:
2024-06-24 14:40:31.017 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]STATEMENT:  VACUUM pg_catalog.pg_class;
2024-06-24 14:40:31.017 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]LOG:  rewritten parse tree:
2024-06-24 14:40:31.017 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]STATEMENT:  VACUUM pg_catalog.pg_class;
2024-06-24 14:40:31.017 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:31.017 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:31.068 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  launched 0 parallel vacuum workers for index cleanup (planned: 2)
2024-06-24 14:40:31.078 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0 (used)
2024-06-24 14:40:31.078 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:31.419 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]STATEMENT:  VACUUM pg_catalog.pg_constraint;
2024-06-24 14:40:31.419 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]LOG:  rewritten parse tree:
2024-06-24 14:40:31.419 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]STATEMENT:  VACUUM pg_catalog.pg_constraint;
2024-06-24 14:40:31.419 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:31.419 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:31.425 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  launched 0 parallel vacuum workers for index cleanup (planned: 2)
2024-06-24 14:40:31.426 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:31.426 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:31.426 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:31.426 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:31.584 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:31.584 KST [237330][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]LOG:  duration: 164.727 ms

2024-06-24 14:40:33.034 KST [243981][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:33.034 KST [243980][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  CommitTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: STARTED; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:33.035 KST [243981][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:33.035 KST [243980][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]DEBUG:  StartTransaction(1) name: unnamed; blockState: DEFAULT; state: INPROGRESS, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0
2024-06-24 14:40:33.035 KST [243981][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]LOG:  statement: select count(*) from sync.exp_code where code = 'test0' and table_name = 'SYNC1';
2024-06-24 14:40:33.035 KST [243980][][mig-pg-arm-241-f.eccenter.com]LOG:  statement: select count(*) from sync.exp_code where code = 'test2' and table_name = 'SYNC1';




Is the vacuum actually finished, or is still stuck some place holding a lock?  You say it was on partitioned tables, but then later say it ran on pg_catalog.  That seems inconsistent. What motivated you to do this?  You usually don't run vacuum full unless there is some kind of problem, and if there was already a problem, maybe that is the source of the issue.

I ran a vacuum full operation to reduce the size of the partitioned table and a few hours after the vacuum full was completed, a cpu rise occurred with the startup session. I was looking for when the startup session occurred and I checked that it happened when the pg_catalog table autovacuum turned around.

The startup process is the process that performs crash recovery after a crash. So your database must have crashed. Examine the logs for the cause.
Based on your description, the problem may well have been that the database ran out of disk space during VACUUM (FULL). If PostgreSQL cannot create a new WAL (transaction log) segment, for example because it is out of disk space, it will crash and try to restart.

There are two different things using the title 'startup'.  One is the name of the process which handles crash recovery and hot standby.  This is what I first assumed you had, as it just like your title "postgres: startup". But there should only be one (at most) of these processes at at time, not dozens.
The other thing is a phase a client backend goes through very briefly after authentication finished but before it is ready to process commands from the client. In my hands this looks more like "postgres: jjanes jjanes [local] startup", where the extra tokens correspond to the username, database, and IP the backend is servicing.  Based on the additional information you provided, I think this is the thing you are seeing, although I don't know why it is using the more concise format for the title string rather than the longer one I see. During this phase it must be consulting the system catalogs, and if doing this is very slow because of extreme bloat or a missing index or something, it could explain many processes piling up at this stage. But I don't know exactly what all catalogs would be consulted at this point.
Another possibility is that a catalog table is not bloated or slow, but just locked, which will block new connections from starting up at all.  For example, if one session has locked the "pg_database" table in access exclusively mode, no other session will be able to startup until the lock is released.  Now in my hands the process title looks like "postgres: jjanes jjanes [local] startup waiting" when this is happening, but since your process titles work differently than mine do I guess it shouldn't be surprising that you see something slightly different.
